# Possibility of Deploying Substrate Kitties to Testnet

Tags: rococo, westend, substrate-kitties-chain, test-network

I've just completed the Substrate Kitties tutorial. Since I've created my own chain in my own local environment, I was wondering if it's possible for me to deploy my Substrate Kitties chain on to the Westend or Rococo test networks. I've tried looking online for information, but there doesn't seem to be much. Would really appreciate any help that points me in the right direction.

I've looked up https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-sync but when I try to start my node, I get an error that the file does not exist.

Comment: Where did you find that broken link? please do report it in an issue on the offending repo if the docs or wiki :)

Comment: It is _not_ suggested at the moment to try and add a "dummy" parachain just to test things out. Westend doens't allow for general parachains and likely will not, and rococo is really for testing _staging ready_ chains that are looking to launch on Kusama while it's still a more manual an limited availability zone for open slots.

Comment: please use instead https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet or https://github.com/open-web3-stack/parachain-launch to test locally if you don't want to manually configre a parachain similar to kitties, if so, please follow the cumulus tutorial: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/cumulus/start-relay/

Answer (score 1):

At the moment of writing Westend is not available for public testing. Though you should be able to request a temporary slot for Rococo by opening an issue [here](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/issues/new/choose).
Although, I believe you won't leverage Rococo that much. It provides a good environment for testing as you are building something that will end up being production material, for testing the outcome of a tutorial my take is that the ux you will get is not going to be that different from what you can experience by running your own relay.